# MaskROM Boot Loader for ARM Cortex Cores or Application Code?

Tags: arm, rom, core, soc

Could someone clear the confusion whether the purpose of a MaskROM or just a ROM boot loader is to load and then start executing **any secondary core1/core2/core3** (not master or primary core0) or does this type of boot loader only load application code such as an OS or user application code ? It is correct to assume that all cores (ARM Cortex) are typically loaded into RAM and then get executed when the core is powered on ? The context of this question could apply to the Qualcomm Snapdragon Processos SoC.

Comment: You question mixes generality with specific assumptions, asks a number of qustions, and uses a lot of 'or' without clarifying the associations. Hence I can't make much sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

*boot loader is to load and then start executing any secondary core1/core2/core3 (not master or primary core0)*

Boot loaders do not 'run the core'. The core runs the boot loader.

*or does this type of boot loader only load application code such as an OS or user application code ?*

*It is correct to assume that all cores (ARM Cortex) are typically loaded into RAM and then get executed when the core is powered on ?*

This question is garbled; what usually happens is that the first bootloader running on the first core loads some software, sets up the address where the secondary cores should start loading and executing code (usually from RAM), and then turns them on.

The first core usually starts loading and executing code from internal ROM or Flash.

Comment: Hello pjc50. I'm sorry but I still cannot understand your last line of comment whether it means that the primary or main core0 code is stored in ROM or flash memory or is it etched into the die using silicon gates ? If it is etched onto the die using silicon gates then how is it possible for core0 to be stored in ROM or flash memory ? Taking the Qualcomm Snapdragon SoC as an example are you saying the main or primary core0 is stored in ROM or flash memory like binary code such as an OS or an user application is typically stored ? Thank you

Comment: The "core" *is* the hardware, the silicon gates. It runs code. The code is stored in ROM or Flash. I'll insert the word 'code' to clarify this.